# Binding properties Content, Background etc in MapItemsControl Pushpin

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I have a model:

```
public class GYPushpin : GYEntity
    {   
        private GeoCoordinate _coordinate;

        public GeoCoordinate Coordinate
        {
           get
           {
             return _coordinate;
           }
           set
           {
             if (value != _coordinate)
             {
                 _coordinate = value;
                 NotifyPropertyChanged("Coordinate");
             }
           }
        }

        //.............

    }
```

and `MapItemsControl`:

```
<toolkit:MapItemsControl>
                        <toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <toolkit:Pushpin 
                                                 GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coordinate}"                                                 
                                                 Background="{Binding Background}"  
                                                 Content="{Binding ContentPushpin}"
                                                 Tag="{Binding Tag}"   
                                                 Tap="userPushpin_Tap">                                 
                                 </toolkit:Pushpin>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                        
                    </toolkit:MapItemsControl>
```

I use DataBinding and filling List in UI thread:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
       {                                
           foreach (GYUser friend in friends)
              {
                   ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush()
                                    {
                                        ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("http://my_url" + string.Format(friend.Avatar)))
                                    };
                   Brush markerColor = friend.Sex == 1 ? new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, 71, 188, 225)) : new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, 246, 109, 128));
                   var content = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle()
                                    {
                                        Fill = image,
                                        StrokeThickness = 10,
                                        Height = 50,
                                        Width = 50
                                    };

                                    var pin = new GYPushpin()
                                    {
                                        Coordinate = new GeoCoordinate()
                                        {
                                            Longitude = friend.Longitude,
                                            Latitude = friend.Latitude,
                                        },
                                        ContentPushpin = content,
                                        Background = markerColor,

                                    };
                    //add pin in binding collection
              }
       }
```

I have a lot of users and I must do work in UI thread, because I use `ImageBrush`, `Shapes`, etc. Can I do work it in background? I mean binding Content and Background properties in another way. After all, MVVM should allow to work in background with the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create the elements in code but instead create them within the xaml template. You bind to the properties in the model (in this case it would be the Friend class.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <toolkit:Pushpin 
        GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coordinate}"                                                 
        Background="Blue"             
        Tag="{Binding Tag}"   
        Tap="userPushpin_Tap">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Sex}" Value="1">
                <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background">
                    <ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                    </ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                </ec:ChangePropertyAction>
            </ec:DataTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Image Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding Avatar}"/>
    </toolkit:Pushpin>
</DataTemplate>
```

With this example you do not need the special GYPushpin but only the Friend class. With this example your Friend class would need to have a complete url to the image and would need a GeoCoordinate.

This example uses the expression sdk. you need to add the following namespaces to your xaml

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```